# pl/sql loop through the table and pass the each entry of the row to a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, for-loop, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I have a table with three columns (table_name, column_name, data_type), I am trying to pass values of these three columns  as parameter to a stored procedure in a loop.

Now, I have a developed very basic code to check if the looping works fine.

```
DECLARE
 
  cursor c1 is 
    select table_name, column_name, data_type from table_list;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1 LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.table_name||' ' ||i.column_name ||''||i.data_type);
   
    
  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Update on the issue: loop is working fine, but when I call the procedure as shown in below code it gives me an error

```
DECLARE
 
  cursor c1 is select table_name, column_name,data_type from table_list;

BEGIN
  FOR i IN c1 LOOP

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.table_name||' ' ||i.column_name ||' '||i.data_type);
    UPD_PII_DATA(i.table_name,i.column_name,i.data_type);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i.table_name|| ' '|| ' and column '|| i.column_name|| ' completed test');

  END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error at line 1
> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> ORA-06512: at "MP_ODI.UPD_PII_DATA", line 13
> ORA-06512: at line 9
> ORA-06512: at line 9

> could please help me on this error

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it, you'd just *call* the procedure and pass values retrieved by the cursor. With a little bit less typing:

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT table_name, column_name, data_type FROM table_list)
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (i.table_name || ' ' || i.column_name || '' || i.data_type);

      -- call the procedure, pass values
      my_procedure (i.table_name, i.column_name, i.data_type);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hi @littlefoot, I have call the proc but i am getting an error as :   

Error at line 1
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "MP_ODI.UPD_PII_DATA", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 9
ORA-06512: at line 9

Comment: As you were told, you're referencing a table which either doesn't exist, or - if it does - you don't have privileges to use it. If latter, does it - by any chance - belong to another user? If so, did you grant privileges on it via **role**? If so, it won't work in **named stored procedures** so you'll have to grant privileges **directly** (i.e. not via role).